# lunch a modal after registration login if form in invalid , Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

i want to lunch a modal if the information put on the Form Is incorrect.

Here is the view code :

def ajouterClient(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":

    form = ClientForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        erreur = "erreur"
        return render(request, 'frontend/home.html' , locals())
```

And Here is the template code:

```
{% if erreur == "erreur" %}
    <div class="modal fade" id="erreur" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="erreurLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header bg-dark text-white">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginLabel">Erreur</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close bg-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body bg-light">

              <h1>Veuillez remplir tous les champs correctement</h1>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#erreur').modal('show')
         });
    </script>

{% endif %}

<!-- End Erreur Modal ajout -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem , im working with boostrap 5 on my project, for some reason the code between the script Tag didn't work, but when i added the CDN of jquery-2.1.1.js , the problem was fixed.